# default value only set after clearing the cache

Tags: forms

I'm trying to set a default value to a HS select but It's working only after clear the cache or for authenticated user .

Here's the code

```
'#default_value' => array($_SESSION['location_current_tid']);
```

Comment: Take a look at the FAPI here http://drupalcode.org/project/hierarchical_select.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/API.txt

Comment: Drupal forms are cached, so your problem could be that default value is only set the first time form is built. 

Try disabling cache if it's set.